# Parse String date in (yyyy-MM-dd) format

Tags: java, date, parsing

I have a string in the form "2013-09-18". I want to convert it into a java.util.Date.
I am doing this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse(currentDateText);
```

The convertedCurrentDate  is coming as 'Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013'

I want my output in the form '2013-09-18'

Hour, minutes and seconds shouldnt come and it should be in the form yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: `parse` is for converting a `String` to a `Date`. To do the opposite, use `format`.

Answer (score 41):

You may need to `format` the out put as follows.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse("2013-09-18");
String date=sdf.format(convertedCurrentDate );
System.out.println(date);
```

Use

```
String convertedCurrentDate =sdf.format(sdf.parse("2013-09-18"));
```

Output:

```
2013-09-18
```

Comment: Hi, How can i get  java.util.Date in the (yyyy-MM-dd) format with return type of Date(java.util.Date)?

Comment: You cannot. A `Date` does not and cannot have a format in it.

Comment: By default, parsing is lenient. Call `setLenient(false)` if you need to disable it -  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)

Comment: I know it is not related but just in case you want to convert it to java.sql.Date instead of  java.util.Date, there is an easier way here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18439059/1572286

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2013-09-18" )
```

… and …

```
myLocalDate.toString()  // Example: 2013-09-18
```

## java.time

The Question and other Answers are out-of-date. The troublesome old legacy date-time classes are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

Your input string happens to comply with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM-DD. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating string representations of date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2013-09-18" );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: It might be worthwhile to show some examples of .parse() options, which was the topic of the original question.

Comment: @jakeblues Thanks for the nudge. Revamped answer to focus on parsing a date-only value.

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a Date object, which is a representation of a certain point in the timeline. This means that it will have all the parts necessary to represent it correctly, including minutes and seconds and so on. Because you initialize it from a string containing only a part of the date, the missing data will be defaulted.

I assume you are then "printing" this Date object, but without actually specifying a format like you did when parsing it. Use the same SimpleDateFormat but call the reverse method, format(Date) as Holger suggested

Comment: +1 this is the only correct answer to the question, since OP seems to be missing the fundamental understanding that a Date is a date, no matter how you print it.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String cunvertCurrentDate="06/09/2015";
Date date = new Date();
date = df.parse(cunvertCurrentDate);
```

Comment: Add an explanation what this code does and why it solves the problem.

Comment: It does not answer the question and it does not solve the problem (at least not correctly/entirely)

Answer (score 1):

I convert String to Date in format ("yyyy-MM-dd")  to save into Mysql data base .

```
 String date ="2016-05-01";
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date parsed = format.parse(date);
 java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
```

sql it's my output in date format