# Understanding how to use SimpleDateFormat with other parameters

Tags: java, date, datetime, object, instance

I'm trying to understand the logic of formatting a date and adding it as a parameter for my objects however finding it difficult. I am trying to use SimpleDateFormat..

```
myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("502","424"));
myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("503","425"));
myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("504","426"));
```

but trying to achieve it accepting

```
myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("502","424", "2020-05-12"));
myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("503","425", "2020-04-22"));
myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("504","426", "2020-05-05"));
```

I have imported both..

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

and have added as parameters/initialized in the Classroom class. Where do I go from here? Appreciate any help I can't seem to find this info

EDIT the attributes of Classroom:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Classroom{      
     private String studID;
     private String subjectID;
     private Date dateEnroled;

     public Classroom(String studID, String subjectID, Date dateEnroled)
     {  
        this.studID = studID; 
        this.courseID = subjectID;
        this.dateEnroled = dateEnroled;
     }
```

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37506250) for how to parse a date in that format into a Date object.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Post some more details e.g. the attributes list of `Classroom`, what you want to do etc. Also, do not use outdated `SimpleDateFormat`; use `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I've added the attributes

Comment: @akuzminykh Trying to achieve it accepting date as part of the enrolment. The tutorials I find only show how to do it for one date

Comment: Do not use outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` instead. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comments, do not use outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for more details.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

class Classroom {
    private String studID;
    private String subjectID;
    private LocalDate dateEnroled;

    public Classroom(String studID, String subjectID, LocalDate dateEnroled) {
        this.studID = studID;
        this.subjectID = subjectID;
        this.dateEnroled = dateEnroled;
    }
    // Getters, setters, hashCode, equals and toString
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClassroom.addEnrolment(new Classroom("502","424", LocalDate.parse("2020-05-12"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor that accepts a string, something like this one:

```
public Classroom(String studID, String subjectID, String dateEnroled)
{  
    this.studID = studID; 
    this.courseID = subjectID;
    this.dateEnroled = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                       .parse(dateEnroled);
}
```

Comment: Do not encourage to use outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. You should have given some example using `LocalDat`e and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Actually the original question was about `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, so this is what I use in my answer. I am not here to evangelize people to the third or fourth attempt for a proper date/time library in java ;-)